# Why did my USB-C monitor stop working even though I didn't change anything?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have a MacBook Pro with 4 USB-C ports (it's the generation that has the Touch Bar nobody likes). I have a Dell USB-C monitor. I have used the two for months together and had no problems. Then a few days ago, the monitor just stopped getting a signal from the USB-C port. Same cable. I tried all 4 ports. I tried to force Detect Displays on the Mac. I tried cycling through inputs on the monitor. The monitor works. The Mac makes a sound and flashes when I plug it in so it's like it knows it's there, but I can't get it to drive the display. Unsure if this was the newest Ventura Update that created the problem. What else is there to try?

Comment: You make the statement “the monitor works.”  How do you know this?  Did you test the monitor on a different computer?

Comment: @Allan the OSD on the monitor works. It is able to show me that it's waiting for a signal, not detecting one, and then going to sleep.

Comment: OSD is typically an RGB signal injected into the current display signal coming from the computer.  This only means the LCD panel is working not that the video interface is working.  Try on a different computer to ensure it’s working.

Answer (score 0):

I had to physically unplug the monitor. The problem survived a Mac restart. There's probably some USB-hub or other display-handling firmware in the monitor that gets confused and needs resetting.